# Mobile Safari - fun with focus()

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile, safari

I am working on a web app to be delivered exclusively to iPad clients using the Mobile Safari browser. My form has two input fields that will both be populated with data from a paired Bluetooth barcode scanner.

When the first field is scanned, the following javascript watches for a return keypress, which parses the incoming string and then sets focus to a quantity field...

```
    function tabtoquantity(e) {
    keyEntry = event.keyCode; 
    if(keyEntry == '13') {
        var barcode = document.test.barcodefield.value;
        var labeltext = barcode.split("*");
        document.test.itemkey.value = labeltext[0];
        document.test.description.value = labeltext[1];
        document.test.lotno.value = labeltext[2];
        document.test.datercvd.value = labeltext[3];
        document.test.binno.value = labeltext[4];
        document.test.unitwgt.value = labeltext[5];
        document.test.slot.value = labeltext[6];
        document.test.allergens.value = labeltext[7];
        document.test.kosher.value = labeltext[8];

        //document.test.barcodefield.disabled="true";
        //document.test.barcodefield.style.display="none";

        document.test.scanqty.focus();
    }
    else if((keyEntry < '48') || (keyEntry > '57'))  {
        return false;             
    }
}
```

This all works great, except that it does not set focus to my scanqty field.

Oddly enough, I have a button beside the scanqty field that onClick calls the following function:

```
    function qtyreset() {
    document.test.scanqty.value = '';
    document.test.scanqty.focus();
}
```

I'm at a loss as to why the same command works in one instance and not in the other. The functionality works as intended in regular Safari.

Maybe it's relevant (?) but Mobile Safari's form assistant (Prev and Next buttons) comes up when I load the page but disappears after I scan data into the first field...where I want it to set focus to the scanqty field, but seems to set focus nowhere.

I appreciate any input/help.

Comment: Why are you using the enter key? Traditionally it submits the form. In desktop browsers, tab will move to the next field, in mobile Safari, the "Next" button will do the same. Then use tabIndex to set the focus on the *scanqty* field and *barcodefield.onblur* to call the listener.

Comment: More accurately, the enter key is a character appended by the barcode scanner to the scanned data. I suppose I could program it to append a tab character instead and parse the data string onblur instead of watching for a particular keypress.  Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Bill, if you have control over the scanners output you might want to have it dump everything in one input box and parse/redistribute the data. I am very skeptical that there are any guarantees about keyboard <-> input element focus and that any solution involving dynamic focus switching will be fragile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that focus() works only, if you have added the site to the home screen and has opened the site with this link.